# Minify a CSS and HTML file to the same location using Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, postcss

I have two files, one CSS and one HTML in these locations:

```
resources/js/example/file.css
resources/js/example/file.html
```

What I would like to do using Laravel Mix (webpack) is

- Minify the CSS file into `file.min.css` into the same directory
- Minify the HTML file into `file.min.html` into the same directory

I have tried:

```
mix.postCss('resources/js/example/file.css', 'resources/js/example/file.min.css', [
    require('cssnano')
]);
```

But this creates the CSS file in `public/js/example/file.min.css`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want compiled files to be in the public directory. Regardless, you can use `mix.setPublicPath()` to change the output directory. This will tells Mix what you want the basic directory where all of your assets should be compiled to.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('');
mix.postCss('resources/js/example/file.css', 'resources/js/example/file.min.css', []);
```

If you want to Mix and minify HTML files you can install this plugin.

```
npm install minify-html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then add to your webpack...

```
const MinifyHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('minify-html-webpack-plugin');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('');
mix.postCss('resources/js/example/file.css', 'resources/js/example/file.min.css', []);
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new MinifyHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            afterBuild: true,
            src: './resources/js/example',
            dest: './resources/js/example',
            ignoreFileNameRegex: /\.(gitignore|php)$/,
            ignoreFileContentsRegex: /(<\?xml version)|(mail::message)/,
            rules: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeComments: true,
                minifyJS: true,
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

And make a dev or production build. Keep in mind you will have to play around with the src and dest to get the output exactly the way you want it.